# Mabox GL JS - Display Zoom

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How can i display the current zoom level using mapbox ? 
Like this: https://www.nps.gov/npmap/tools/npmap.js/examples/zoomdisplay-control/
I thought it could be easy, like adding navigation control, but seems not. 
First I just added the line

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation());   Add the nav controls
map.getZoom ();                              thought this would add the zoom box...
```

As i saw there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614957/how-can-i-read-current-zoom-level-of-mapbox , I should first create a var ? i tried `var zoom = map.getZoom();`
But then i should create a div reffering to some css to display it ? 
So i tried inspiring by this leaflet plugin https://github.com/azavea/Leaflet.zoomdisplay . I i created a style class`.leaflet-control-zoom-display {`

Then tried to put my var into a container like this :

```
var zoom = map.getZoom (
container: '.leaflet-control-zoom-display');
```

My patchwork isn't working.. i guess there is more code for this ? 
As i am using mapbox gl js and not leaflet, i can't realy use the plugin found on github, but is it possible to fit it to mapbox ? If doiing that, i may change some of code, like that :

```
L.Control.ZoomDisplay = L.Control.extend({
options: {
position: 'topleft' },
```

will it be `Control.ZoomDisplay = Control.extend({
    options: {
    position: 'topleft' },`
just removing the L referring to leaflet is enough ? 
In the top of my html page, should i add a link to the native leaflet also even if i already have one to mapbox ?`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>`